# Apple Photos error: "The library could not be opened. Photos was unable to open the library"

Tags: photos, catalina

I'm running macOS and have a large Photos library on a NAS. When I attempt to open Photos, I get:

[image]

> The library could not be opened.
> Photos was unable to open the library “Photos Library.photoslibrary”. (1000)
> Quit
> Open Other...

or

> Photos was unable to open the library “Photos Library.photoslibrary”. (4302)

The library worked OK before Catalina and Photos went through an extensive library update on first launch. It sorted the pictures, but never created the or displayed the thumbnails. Now, however, it won't open the library at all.

How can I fix my Photos library?

Comment: Can you add any relevant lines from the [Console log for Photos](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/photos-has-attempted-to-repair-the-library/#using-consoleapp-for-error-research)?

Comment: After attempting to rebuild the library, according to the suggestion of @Udhy, I get the following 2 error messages: "Repair Operation Error: error=Error Domain=com.apple.library-repair.error Code=4 "(null)" followed by "Failed to open/create library at: '/Volumes/homes/common/Photos Library.photoslibrary' error: Error Domain=IPXLibraryConnectionControllerErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Volumes/homes/common/Photos%20Library.photoslibrary/, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000030c40f0 {Error Domain=com.apple.library-repair.error Code=4 "(null)"}}"

Comment: If I try to open the library (Choose Other Library...), then I get: The operation couldn’t be completed. (PHPhotosErrorDomain error 1000.)

Comment: ALWAYS BACK UP photoslibrary FIRST! Mac Studio + Ventura was getting "The operation couldn’t be completed. (PHPhotosErrorDomain error 3146.)" So, different error code, but it worked. Remember ALWAYS back up. Best if it goes on a backup drive / separate drive b/c I've had some weird behavior with APFS "duplicates" (Yes I understand how it works, and is supposed to work, but in practice, some special files do not work perfectly to sand box duplicates... sorry, it's just so. Example, vmware fusion virtual machines... that's one fancy file for apple to screw up if you ask me).

Answer (score 7):

Hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd> keys while launching Photos to repair the library.

[image: Repair Library]

> Repair Library
> You are about to repair the library "Photos Library".

You’ll need an Administrator name and password for the computer to authorize running the repair tool.

[image: Photos is trying to repair your photo library.]

Then it will start Repairing your Library.

[image]

It may then switch to "Restoring" your Library:

[image: Restoring...]

Try to repair the library and it should work if it was working without any issue before upgrade.

Comment: After attempting to rebuild the library, according to the suggestion of @Udhy, I get the following 2 error messages: "Repair Operation Error: error=Error Domain=com.apple.library-repair.error Code=4 "(null)" followed by "Failed to open/create library at: '/Volumes/homes/common/Photos Library.photoslibrary' error: Error Domain=IPXLibraryConnectionControllerErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Volumes/homes/common/Photos%20Library.photoslibrary/, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000030c40f0 {Error Domain=com.apple.library-repair.error Code=4 "(null)"}}"